# Counter of login attempts?

Tags: vb6, login-page

I am designing a login page in visual basics 6.0. I have to include a counter such that after three unsuccessful attempts the page will close itself. I have written following code in command button. Although there is no errors but the counter is not working. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim count As Integer
count = 0

If Form1.Text1 = "admin" And Form1.Text2 = "admin" Then
MsgBox "Login Succesfull", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Welcome"
Else
    count = count + 1
    If count = 3 Then
      End
    Else
        MsgBox "Login Unsuccesfull", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Try Again"
        Form1.Text1 = ""
        Form1.Text2 = ""
        Form1.Text1.SetFocus
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just change `Dim` to `Static` so it keeps its value across calls; and get rid of the line that sets it to zero.

Comment: @Idle_Mind You're right, I'd shifted my parameters over :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just change Dim to Static so it keeps its value across calls.  And also get rid of the line that sets it to zero:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Static count As Integer

    If Form1.Text1 = "admin" And Form1.Text2 = "admin" Then
        MsgBox "Login Succesfull", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Welcome"
    Else
        count = count + 1
        If count = 3 Then
          End
        Else
            MsgBox "Login Unsuccesfull", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Try Again"
            Form1.Text1 = ""
            Form1.Text2 = ""
            Form1.Text1.SetFocus
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You set your count to 0 each time that Command1 is clicked. You need to declare `count` outside of that sub & initialise it to 0 elsewhere.

```
Private count As Integer

Private Sub Command1_Click()    
    If Form1.Text1 = "admin" And Form1.Text2 = "admin" Then
        MsgBox "Login Succesfull", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Welcome"
    Else
        count = count + 1

        If count = 3 Then
            End
        Else
            MsgBox "Login Unsuccesfull", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Try Again"
            Form1.Text1 = ""
            Form1.Text2 = ""
            Form1.Text1.SetFocus
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```